# Sum of infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that the following series converges to $1$. $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1}$$
I can't seem to find any good formulas or tricks for a sum like this.

Comment: Do you know of Taylor series? Once you differentiate the formula for a geometric sum it's easy.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337937/why-sum-k-1-infty-frack2k-2).

Comment: Look to plug in 1/2 for $x$ in the derivative of the power series $\sum _{n=0}^\infty x^n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is equal to $\frac14\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\left(\frac12\right)^{k-1}$. Now, use the fact that$$\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)'=(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)'=1+2x+3x^2+\cdots$$when $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
S = \frac{1}{2}+&2\frac{1}{4}+3\frac{1}{8}+\dots\\
\frac{1}{2}S = &\frac{1}{4}+2\frac{1}{8}+3\frac{1}{16}+\dots\\
\frac{1}{2}S = &\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\dots=1\\
S=2
\end{align}$$
I got the third line by subtracting the second from the first.
For the above to be valid, you have to prove the series converges.

Comment: You need a ${1\over2}$ on the right hand side in the third line.