# Average number of comparisons made by the Binary search (summation computation)

Tags: summation

I am trying to find out the average number of comparisons made by the Binary search. In that, I'm confronted with following summation :-

Avg = $(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^{\log_2 n} i*2^i$

In this summation, $i$ are the number of comparisons made at each node in $i^{th}$ level of the Binary tree and $2^i$ is the number of nodes in the tree at level $i$.

Please help me solve this summation. If not completely solve the summation, at least please help me get started.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the partial sum of $n/2^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862128/how-to-find-the-partial-sum-of-n-2n)  Also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119636/formula-for-calculating-sum-n-0mnrn)  [This search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=sum%2C%20%24%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7B2%5En%7D%24&p=1) finds them and others

Comment: Remember, that $\log_2 n$ is not necessarily integer.