# partial sum of $\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{i}{a^i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

From "[How to find the partial sum of n/2n?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862128/how-to-find-the-partial-sum-of-n-2n)" we know that $S_n=2\left(1-\frac1{2^n}-\frac n{2^{n+1}}\right)$ so how can we prove that $\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{i}{a^i} = \frac{(a^{(k+1)}-a(k+1)+k)}{a^k(a-1)^2}$

Comment: So is the running index $i$ or $n$? And what is $k$?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry about that. Now I have changed index into i and k is upper limit of summation.

Comment: Consider https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2862137 with $x=1/a$.

Comment: [This has a name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence#Sum_of_the_terms).

Comment: Thank you very much everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$S_n=~~r+2r^2+3r^3+4r^4+...+nr^n~~~~(1)$$
$$rS_n=~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~r^2+2r^3+3r^4+...+(n-1)r^n+nr^{n+1}~~~~(2)$$Suntrcting (2) from (1), we get
$$(1-r)S_n=r+r^2+r^3+r^4+...r^n-nr^{n+1}$$
$$(1-r)S=r[1+r+r^2+r^3+...+r^{n-1}]-nr^{n+1}$$
$$(1-r)S_n=r\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}-nr^{n+1}$$
$$S_n=\frac{r-(n+1)r^{n+1}+nr^{n+2}}{(1-r)^2}$$
Let $r=1/a$, then
$$S_n=\frac{a^{n+1}-(n+1)a+n}{(1-a)^2a^n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{a^k}$$