# Determine convergence of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the following sequnce converge or diverge? $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{3^n}$$

How are these kinds of problems written down and proven? From my understanding, this will converge to $0$ because the denominator grows at a faster rate than the numerator. Is that all I can do about this problem or is there some more detailed way to solve it?

Comment: Certainly the *terms* of the series will converge to $0$ (essentially for the reason you stated), but the series itself will not tend to $0$, as it consists only of strictly positive terms. Unfortunately, knowing the series terms converge to $0$ is not enough to conclude convergence of the sum. Are you familiar with the ratio test?

Comment: @TheoBendit No. Only one week of classes passed and we just started sequences. Possibly this is all that is expected from me then, maybe. I wanted to check if there was some easy proof that I missed.

Comment: You are asking about the convergence of a *series*, not a sequence. The two concepts are closely related, but they're not the same.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "easier" than ratio test, but certainly an elementary approach is to [compute the partial sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3974846/partial-sum-of-sum-i-1k-fraciai) and then take the limit.

Comment: If you look at [the most frequent sequences-and-series question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series?tab=Frequent) you will learn how to compute the sum of this series exactly.

Answer (score 1):

1)Root test:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test

2)Recall:

$e^n=$

$1+n+n^2/2!+n^3/3!+... > n^3/3!$

$\dfrac{n}{3^n} <\dfrac{n}{e^n} <\dfrac{3!}{n^2};$

$\sum \dfrac {1}{n^2}$ converges (comparison test).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
If your series got strictly positive terms if

$$
\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow} \ell<1
$$
then $\sum u_n $ converges